# Standard way to identify the child records of an Account in an Account Merge Process

Tags: account, merge, process

This is a problem I am facing in the identification of the Child Records that gets moved into a Surviving account, out of the Standard Account Merge process. Is there a way of identification of suck kind of records in SFDC out of box?